# How to log the backend request in haproxy log

Tags: haproxy

Instead of logging the incoming http request how to log the rewritten backend request in HAProxy.

Comment: Not sure what values you want to see logged, but I would take a look at the custom logging in haproxy and see if it can suffice https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.2.4